# How can I detect a tap outside the View in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a React Native application where I have a popover component that I want to close when the user taps outside of it. However, I'm encountering some difficulties in implementing this behavior.

```
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, Pressable, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

import styles from "./styles";
import { IBlock } from "../../types/models";
import { HomeNavigationProp } from "../../types/navigation";

type Props = {
  block: IBlock;
};

const Block = ({ block }: Props) => {
  const [currentLessonIndex, setCurrentLessonIndex] = useState(0);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  const [popoverVisible, setPopoverVisible] = useState(false);

  const navigation = useNavigation<HomeNavigationProp>();

  const handlePressOutside = () => {
    setPopoverVisible(false);
  };

  const onPopoverButtonPress = () => {
    setPopoverVisible(false);
    navigation.navigate("Lesson");
  };

  const onNextLesson = () => {};

  return (
    <View>
      <Pressable onPress={() => setPopoverVisible(true)} style={styles.blockBox}>
        <Text style={styles.boxText}>{block.blockName}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.boxText}>
          {progress} / {block.lessons.length}
        </Text>
      </Pressable>

      {popoverVisible && (
        <View style={styles.popoverBox}>
          <Text style={styles.popoverTitle}>{block.blockName}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.popoverText}>
            Lesson {currentLessonIndex + 1} of {block.lessons.length}
          </Text>
          <Pressable onPress={onPopoverButtonPress} style={styles.popoverButton}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Start</Text>
          </Pressable>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  blockBox: {
    width: 100,
    aspectRatio: 1,
    alignSelf: "center",
    marginBottom: 15,
    padding: 10,
    justifyContent: "center",
    borderRadius: 50,
    backgroundColor: colors.orange50,
  },
  boxText: {
    fontFamily: "mainMed",
    fontSize: 14,
    textAlign: "center",
    color: colors.white,
  },
  popoverBox: {
    position: "absolute",
    alignSelf: "center",
    top: 90,
    zIndex: 2,
    width: "80%",
    borderRadius: 18,
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: colors.green50,
  },
  popoverTitle: {
    fontFamily: "mainBold",
    fontSize: 16,
    color: colors.white,
  },
  popoverText: {
    fontFamily: "mainMed",
    fontSize: 16,
    color: colors.white,
  },
  popoverButton: {
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 10,
    marginTop: 10,
    alignSelf: "stretch",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: colors.white,
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontFamily: "mainBold",
    fontSize: 16,
    color: colors.green50,
  },
});

export default Block;
```

I'm trying to achieve a behavior where tapping outside the popover closes it. I've attempted a few solutions, including wrapping the popover with a `TouchableWithoutFeedback` component, but none of them seem to work as expected.

Comment: Use Pressable instead of TouchableWithoutFeedback.

Comment: @user18309290 Thank you for your response! Could you please provide an example or further explanation of how to use Pressable instead of TouchableWithoutFeedback to achive closing the popover tapping outside of it? I'm relatively new to React Native development, and an example would greatly help me understand how to implement this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.
Note that the backdrop doesn't cover BottomNavigationBar if you have it.

> Added fragments.
> Added a selfclosing pressable behind the box.

```
import { Dimensions } from "react-native";

      {popoverVisible && (
      <>
        <Pressable onPress={onPopoverButtonPress} style={styles.popoverBackdrop} />
        <View style={styles.popoverBox}>
          <Text style={styles.popoverTitle}>{block.blockName}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.popoverText}>
            Lesson {currentLessonIndex + 1} of {block.lessons.length}
          </Text>
          <Pressable onPress={onPopoverButtonPress} style={styles.popoverButton}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Start</Text>
          </Pressable>
        </View>
      </>
      )}
```

```
popoverBackdrop: {
  position: 'absolute',
  width: Dimensions.get('screen').width,
  height: Dimensions.get('screen').height,
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
}
```